# VBA how to use a variable string to call a variable or function?

Tags: vba, excel

I have form inputs called "text1, text2, text2..."  and I have an array of strings to fill the inputs with...

What I want is this....

```
text1.Value = Invoice.input(1)
text2.Value = Invoice.input(2)
text3.Value = Invoice.input(3)
```

but this seems like a lot of typing for something I know can be done with a simple for loop..

```
for loop = 1 To loop = 50 
 text+i.Value = Invoice.input(i)
next loop
```

how can I use text+i to call my var which is actually called text1?

When doing a Google search a few people said to use the Eval() function but this didn't work for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it: (or at least help)

```
Sub ControlName()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 50
        UserForm1.Controls("text" & i).Value = Invoice.input(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you!! UserForm1.Controls("text" & var) works perfectly! been looking for this for some time!!!